# Use inputrc inside sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, jline

I would like these settings to work seamless in my shell as well as in sbt.

Is there something special I need to do to get these working?

My ~/.inputrc:

`\C-Space:complete
\C-i:menu-complete
"\C-f": forward-word
"\C-b": backward-word
"\u26F5": unix-word-rubout
"\C-w": backward-kill-word
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward`